# React state not updating after it returns from function

Tags: reactjs, setinterval, react-state

I have some code that simulates a timer that will look at the start time, store that into localStorage and compare that to Date.now() and will correctly simulate a working timer by updating a state variable that increments on a setInterval every 1 second. It works well even after page reload.

Naturally the timer counts up in milliseconds, so i wrote a function that formats the time into hours:minutes:seconds. The issue now is that the counter, which was updating in real time when unformatted, now that it goes into a function to format, what is returned is correctly formatted but does not increment in real time, i suspect something to do with function not being called again even though the state is being incremented every second.

My question would be is there a way to call the function every time the state changes like a useEffect? Maybe a custom hook?

Here's my code:

```
const date = new Date()
const [time, setTime] = useState(date.getTime())

//starts timer on button click
function startTimer() {
   setStart(true)
   localStorage.setItem('startTime', date.getTime())
}
//converts ms time into hours:minutes:seconds
function msToTime(duration) {                
    let seconds = Math.floor((duration / 1000) % 60),
    minutes = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60)) % 60),
    hours = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24)
    hours = (hours < 10) ? "0" + hours : hours
    minutes = (minutes < 10) ? "0" + minutes : minutes
    seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds
    return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds
} 
//the interval that updates time state every second
useEffect(() => {
   const timer = setInterval(() => {
   setTime(prev => prev+1)
},1000)
return () => {
  clearInterval(timer) 
}     
},[time])

//return the difference between start and time state and formats it
return <h3>{msToTime(Math.abs(+localStorage.getItem('startTime') - time))}</h3>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is fine in your code except that you have overseen one compatibility issue. In your `setTime` function, the *prev* argument is in milliseconds, but you're adding only one millisecond to it every second. Change it to the following:

```js
setTime(prev =>  prev + 1000)
```

You can also use:

```js
setTime(date.getTime())
```

Comment: wow can't beleive i missed that. thanks lol !